# Angular image source not working

Tags: angular

I am having problem with img src in my angular project. After some research, I moved my images to the assets folder, which got rid of my error 404 message. When I upload my background image, it works fine, but when I am trying to add images to my slideshow, it does not show any image, it doesn't give me any error messages. After inspecting the element, this is the size it shows, I am not sure if this is the problem with 0x0 pixels[image]

In my component file

```
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit { 
  backgroundImage: any = '../assets/background_image.jpg';
  body_image1: any = '../assets/body_image1.png'; 
  body_image2: any = '../assets/body_image2.png';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

component.html file

```
<body background="{{backgroundImage}}"> <!-- Works fine -->
<!-- Bottom does not work -->
<div class="body_slideshow" style="max-width:400px">
        <img class="mySlides" src="{{body_image1}}" style="width:88.25%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="{{body_image2}}" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

Comment: Try `[src]="body_image1"` instead. If you inspect the element, is it pointing at the right url?

Comment: Try `body_image1: any = 'assets/body_image1.png';` (without `../`).

Comment: I tried both but no image is displaying on the webpage. How do I check if it is pointing at the right url @user184994

Comment: Depends which browser you're using. Something like: right click on the image -> inspect / inspect element -> check the value of the src attribute in the DOM inspector

Comment: On my IDE, when I try to follow the link for src="{{body_image1}}", it tells me File not Found. It sends to me a different location than the one I specified

Comment: Not in your IDE, in your browser.

Comment: On my broswer, it does show the correct path for the image as well as it shows the correct picture I wanted in the DOM inspector

Comment: Do you see a broken image link instead of your image?

Comment: There is no broken image link, it just a blank empty space

Comment: Okay, it may be a CSS issue. Can you try changing your style attribute on the img to `style="width: 400px; height: 400px"` just to see if it displays the image?

Comment: I tried to change the width and height but didn't work. I saw that the image in the inspector had a 0x0 pixels

Comment: If you can create a stackblitz or blunker to reproduce the issue, it would be much easier for us to help

Comment: Stackblithz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tk2xda If it does not work here is my github link: https://github.com/na2193/DayCare.git

Comment: You're hiding the image with `display: none` on the `mySlides` css class

Comment: @user184994 Thank You, wow I don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 0):

Your css class `.myClass` under `homepage.component.css` has `display: none`, remove that, it should work fine.